# Draw a 3D representation of an n-ary tree on an HTML canvas?

Tags: javascript, data-structures

Where do I start?

I have the tree data which I can realise as JSON or whatever. 
I would like to draw a 3D representation of this structure on the 2D plane of an HTML canvas. 
I’m happy with JS / CoffeeScript but no recent experience of JS graphics / data-visualisation / graph-visualisation libraries.

Comment: *"Where do I start?"* ... Stackoverflow isn't a *"how to"* tutorial service. Perhaps you should explore examples in some of the available libraries. Also not at all clear what you expect for display

Comment: I am asking for a pointer to available libraries.

Comment: BTW Stackoverflow is a forum for collaboration where We are used to giving to others and receiving from others courteous postings or just ignoring posts where I cannot offer help or do not have an answer.

Comment: Fine but asking about libraries to use is completely off topic as outlined in the [help]. And again, we really have no idea what the specific effect is you are looking for

Comment: "*Stackoverflow is a forum*"... (don't say that too loud) SO is a Q/A repository. Not a forum. And without Answerable Questions, there is no Answer nor knowledge sharing.